# Как достать response из VOLLEY?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

У меня есть проблемы с пониманием VOLLEY.

```
public void JsonArrayRequest(){
    shops = new ArrayList<>();
    request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}
```

По логике, я вызываю этот реквест откуда-то сверху, со слоя с логикой, я хочу вернуть туда же респонс от его отработки и распарсить, после чего отдать на отрисовку.
Проблема в том, что я могу работать с response только из метода onResponse.
Я пытался:
Обьявить в классе другой JSONArray и мапить этот response туда и к нему сделать геттер , но как только я что-то делаю с ним не из onResponse - он пуст(.
Как правильно забрать этот респонс и отдать в другой слой?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что запрос выполняется асинхронно, и Вы можете использовать его результат только когда будет получен ответ - вызван `onResponse`, соответственно логику работы с результатом нужно запускать из него же, а не сразу после отправки запроса.

Answer (score 0):

В метод `JsonArrayRequest` пробрасывать колбек. А в `onResponse` вызывать этот колбек и прокидывать туда данные.